# adding icons to custom Eclipse editor hovers

Tags: eclipse

I've created my own extension to DefaultTextHover within my custom Eclipse editor, and wanted to add icons to the hover -- similar to what the JDT does when I hover over a program element.

Currently, my implementation of getHoverInfo returns the appropriate String for the hover itself.  But I would like the hover to also contain an icon -- similar to what I'm already using in my editor's outline.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your extension to `DefaultTextHover` implement `ITextHoverExtension` which adds the new method `getHoverControlCreator`. This method returns a `IInformationControlCreator` which is used to create the `IInformationControl` which is used to display the hover information.

`IInformationControl` creates the hover and can interpret the hover text any way it wishes (as HTML for example).

There is a `DefaultInformationControl` implementation of `IInformationControl` available which does a lot of the work for you. This requires you to provide a class implementing `DefaultInformationControl.IInformationPresenter` and `DefaultInformationControl.IInformationPresenterExtension`.

There is an **internal** JFace class `HTMLTextPresenter` which can be used as an example for implementing the information presenter (since this is internal you should not use it directly).

Comment: i'm doing something like this currently, using `DefaultInformationControl` such that i can use simple HTML tags (eg., <b>) in my text....  can i in fact add <img> tags to this HTML -- and if so, where is my "current directory" relative to my icons folder???

Comment: Use `FileLocator` to find resources in a plugin